# Shell script to check if specified files were updated in folder B compared to same files in folder A

Tags: linux, shell, grep, diff

I've spent lots of hours thinking about how to make a script that ensures that i need to update *.txt files in a folder. The two situations in which i don't need an update:

1. When in both A and B folders all the *.txt files are identical, both quantity of those files and their names are the same.
2. Files in folder A were updated / modified later than in folder B.

I've made a script using `diff folderA folderB | grep "\*.txt"`. But it still compares only *.txt without looking at date_modified stats.

Just to further clarify things: folder A is to be updated, it is local, folder B is on the server.
Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: `man rsync`  This problem has already been solved.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i find that solved question? I've searched and read for tags shell diff but haven't found anything that could include the date_modified parameter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disregard that. Obviously @WilliamPursell has answered my above question already. Thank you.